# Create JSON array from existing array with different key-value pairs

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I need to transform the following JSON array:

```
    [{
    "ID": 2,
    "NAME": "name_1",
    "UUID": "something"
    }, {
    "ID": 3,
    "NAME": "name_2",
    "UUID": "something-else"
    }]
```

Into a JSON array like this:

```
    [{
    "ATTRIBUTE": "ID",
    "EXAMPLE_1": "2",
    "EXAMPLE_2": "3"
    }, {
    "ATTRIBUTE": "NAME",
    "EXAMPLE_1": "name_1",
    "EXAMPLE_2": "name_2"
    }, {
    "ATTRIBUTE": "UUID",
    "EXAMPLE_1": "something",
    "EXAMPLE_2": "something-else"
    }
```

As you can see i need the key from the first array to be a value in the second array and i only want to get it once. After the first iteration i wan to append a value to an object but i need to find the object by the ATTRIBUTE value.

I am quite new to C# but i was planning on using [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: Please share your C# code with us.  Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service, but we would be happy to help you get your code working.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service. We're happy to help you get your solution working, though. Please show us what you've tried

Comment: After you have parsed the original JSON into a sequence of objects, you can loop through the sequence and collect for each of the three original attributes into three new objects with the three new attributes. (You can find out more about this kind of process, by search for "pivoting data".) Then you can serialize those objects into your new JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to accomplish this with **Linq**, you could use the following.

```
var json = @" [{
'ID': 2,
'NAME': 'name_1',
'UUID': 'something'
}, {
'ID': 3,
'NAME': 'name_2',
'UUID': 'something-else'
}]";

var newData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(json)
                    .SelectMany(x=> x.Select(c=>new {c.Key,c.Value}))
                    .GroupBy(x=>x.Key)
                    .Select(x=> (new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>{new KeyValuePair<string,string>("ATTRIBUTE",x.Key)}
                            .Union(x.ToList().Select((f,index)=> new KeyValuePair<string,string>($"EXAMPLE_{index+1}",f.Value)).ToList())))
                    .Select(x=>x.ToDictionary(c=>c.Key,c=>c.Value));

var newDataSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newData);
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "ATTRIBUTE": "ID",
    "EXAMPLE_1": "2",
    "EXAMPLE_2": "3"
  },
  {
    "ATTRIBUTE": "NAME",
    "EXAMPLE_1": "name_1",
    "EXAMPLE_2": "name_2"
  },
  {
    "ATTRIBUTE": "UUID",
    "EXAMPLE_1": "something",
    "EXAMPLE_2": "something-else"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are looking for you can Serialize a list of `Dictionary` objects containing the values for each property of your model that you wish to include.

For example:

```
    //this is the List that you will use to produce the expected JSON format
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> values = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

    //setup a Dictionary for every property you want to include
    Dictionary<string, object> ids = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    ids.Add("Attribute", "Id");
    for(int i = 0; i < examples.Count; i++)
        ids.Add("Example_" + (i + 1).ToString(), examples[i].Id);

    //add the dictionary to the list to be included in the JSON
    values.Add(ids);

    //serialize
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
```

There are other ways to fill the list of `Dictionary` object, for example using Reflection, but this is just to demonstrate the idea.

Full working example in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZexGk9).

HTH

Comment: Thanks, will try this solution. I'll just have to adapt it and make it generic as the input JSON key names are dynamic.